# Does padding an AES key hurt security (besides lowering the strength of the key)?

Tags: aes, key-generation

I've been reading about [solitare](http://www.schneier.com/solitaire.html) and its weaknesses, and thinking about clever ways of hiding keys. It seems like you could encode an 52-bit AES key in the vertical orientation of cards in a deck (or 104-bit if it wouldn't be suspicious that you have cards flipped back-to-front).

What I'm wondering is, would it be safe to just zero-pad the rest of the key, or are there problems if part of the key is known? A more practical comparison seems to be AES-128 and AES-256: If I padded a 128-bit AES key for AES-256, would it be weaker than the original key with AES-128?

Comment: Might be best on crypto.stackexchange.com?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to Crypto.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no known weakness in having a "padded key" for AES, besides the obvious weakness of the key space size being reduced (a 52-bit key space can be explored exhaustively with some PC and some patience). However, AES security was not studied thoroughly for that kind of property, so anything goes; for instance, AES is known to be relatively flaky with regards to [related key attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Related-key_attack), which operate in a similar area. To be safer, consider hashing your key elements with SHA-256, and using the hash output as key for AES.